# How do I modify a library in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm using a library that draws barcodes and under them it drows the barcode number, however it draws text just in black color. I found the code that chooses the color during this operations, however when I try to change this code library from Colors.black to Colors.white and I save it, it doesn't save for some reason. So I suppose there is a different way to modify code from library, but I don't know how.

Comment: can u add library name or github link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Gabriel, You can easily copy .dart files from the package/library you're using to your project and modify the code to your liking. For e.g. if you are using https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch, then you can access the source code from the GitHub location of the package in pub.dev and download it from GitHub,

[image: GitHub Link]

[image: Github]

You can then copy .dart files from `<project>/lib` to your `<project>/lib` and modify them accordingly. Make sure you add reference in the source code to credit the original developers and add their GitHub link.

Good luck!